# Ayuda con problema con borrar de firebase firestore utilizando un arreglo de react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

Estoy intentando borrar la cardslider indicada pero solo estoy borrando la card 0 como borrar la cardslider con el indice correcto
Aqui construyo mi cardslider estoy trayendo de mi base todos los datos y los voy introduciendo en mis tarjetas uno por uno intente de varias maneras y no pude arreglarlo el problema es que no se como saber cual es la posicion indicada de la card intebte mandar el index pero me lo manda por cada iteracion entonces la funcion se acciona cada vez lo cual no deberia de ocurrir solo quiero eliminar la cardslider adecuada que se pida en un determinado momento no la 0 
Quiero borrar de mi base la cardslider adecuada sin importat si es la 0 o la 10 o la 50

```
      const TabCultivos = this.state.dbconst.map(
    (doc, index) => {
      return (
        <View>
        <CardSilder style={{marginTop: 30}}>
          <View style={{height: 90, }}>
            <Text style={styles.labels}>
                 Especie: {doc.data().Especie}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.labels}>
                Variedad: {doc.data().Variedad}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.labels}>
                Tipo: {doc.data().Tipo}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{height: 90, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', backgroundColor: '#008080'}}>
             <MaterialIcons
              name="edit"
              style={styles.iconStyle}
          />
          </View>
          <View style={{height: 90, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', backgroundColor: '#ff0000'}}>
             <MaterialIcons
              name="delete"
              style={styles.iconStyle}
              onPress={this.deleteConstCultivo}
          />
          </View>
        </CardSilder>
      </View>
      );
    }
  );
```

Aqui esta la funcion flecha borrar

```
deleteConstCultivo = () => {
Alert.alert(
  "Borrar Constante",
  "¿Esta seguro que desea borrar esta constante?",
  [
    {
      text: "Cancelar",

      style: "Cancelar"
    },
    {
      text: "Aceptar",
      onPress: () => {
        fs.collection("const")
          .doc(this.state.dbconst[0].id)
          .delete()
          .then(() => {
            Alert.alert(
              "",
              "borrado",
              [],
              {
                cancelable: true
              }
            );
          });

      }
    }
  ],
  { cancelable: false }
);
```

};

Comment: Unexpected Error:  Text is repeat 100 times